# Working with Curved Trajectory

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The question is as follows:

> After rolling off the end of a ramp, a ball follows
>   a curved trajectory to the floor. To test a theory that says that the trajectory can be described by an equation $y = h − ax^2$, Sasha makes some measurements. The end of the ramp is 128 cm above the floor, and the ball lands 80 cm downrange, as shown in the figure. In order to catch the ball in mid-flight with a cup that is 78 cm above the floor, where should Sasha place the cup?

[image: The attached diagram]

I labeled the top part of the parabola with coordinates as $(80, 128)$, the cup $(x, 78)$ and the part where the ball will land $(x,0)$.

I don't know what to do with these information afterwards. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(d)=h-ad^2$$
Since we want $f(0)=128$, we have
$$f(0)=h=128$$
so
$$f(d)=128-ad^2$$
Since we want $f(80)=0$, we have
$$f(80)=128-6400a=0$$
$$a=\frac{128}{6400}=\frac{1}{50}$$
so
$$f(d)=128-\frac{d^2}{50}$$
Now, we want to find the distance $d_c$ at which the height of the ball is $78$ centimeters, we simply solve:
$$f(d_c)=128-\frac{d_c^2}{50}=78$$
Can you solve the equation
$$128-\frac{d_c^2}{50}=78$$
for $d_c$ to find the distance from the table at which the cup should be placed?